# Using express session with mongoStore and database authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, session

I have an object containing config values like so:

```
var db = {
  name: "Auth",
  port: "27017",
  host: "localhost",
  user: "testUser",
  pass: "testPassword",  
  secret: "62y4q8C03l3t"
}
```

Now I'm using [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) with [connect-mongostore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongostore) to store session data in my MongoDB.

```
app.use(session({
  resave: true,
  secret: db.secret,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store: new mongoStore({
    "db" : db.name,
    "host": db.host,
    "port": db.port,
    "username": db.user, 
    "password": db.pass
  })
}));
```

Previously I had no authentication on my Mongo databases and this worked fine. However, I have just got authentication working on my databases, and now get the following error message on the above:

```
sessions <MongoError: not authorized for query on Auth.system.indexes>
```

Comment: Sounds to me like a permissions error or something? I assume you've verified the username and password passed to mongoStore?

Comment: @AlexFord Yeh it's the same username, password and other details I use in my normal mongo connection. That works fine.

Answer (score 0):

What roles do your user have on the Auth database? To access the indexes, the readWrite role is not enough, you should have the dbAdmin role.

Comment: Yeh it's a global role to control all databases, reading, writing, everything.

Comment: The user has `role: "root"`. This seems to have given sufficient privileges so far, this is the first time I've experienced any problem. Is that not the right role? I want this same user to be able to read and write to any database.

Comment: You should have a look to the role documentation:
http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/built-in-roles/
`root does not include any access to collections that begin with the system. prefix.`
The error shows an access denied on Auth.system.indexes, so you should try adding the role dbAdmin on the Auth database to your user, even if he has already the root role.

Comment: I fixed the problem by adding `authSource: "admin"` to my mongostore connection object. It was happy with the `role: root`.